# how to calculate a method's call frequency

Tags: load, rate

I want to wirte a simple load balancer.

Let's say, I have two server run exactly same webservice.  The load balancer need to know how many times the webservice was called recently on each server. The lower called server will be recommend to be used by client.

The webservice can be called by many clients at same time.

I need a way to calculate how many times a method was called in last minute.
It better not use any lock to block the concurrent invoke and not to use too much memory. The times a method was called doesn't have to  accurate.

Answer (score 0):

So how about a single threaded async io (ie node.js or twisted/tornado?) the load balancer would route requests, while it maintains the counts necessary (no locks required)? Both updating a single count as we as handing the request off should be fast, "non blocking" operations.

Both libraries are basically io multiplexing tools that fully utilize one single thread rather than create multiple threads. Given that most of the runtime of network applications is waiting for i/o, the ability of a single thread to execute other code while i/o is coming makes it able to match or exceed performance of multi-threaded servers. It uses epoll/select like os functions to do this. One of the benefits is that synchronizing is not required.

Some fairly minimal working samples for a proxy in tornado (python) and node.js:
https://codeforgeek.com/2015/12/reverse-proxy-using-expressjs/
https://gist.github.com/netdesign/1267537/635425784393fc8397fb928d1e573e4495696d82

To use a moving total, you will need to define a window (estimated calls per period defined in window).

Then (pseudo code):

```
 var server1sum = 0, 
     server2sum = 0,
     routes = [],
     window = <number of requests to keep>;

 function route(request):
       if server1sum < server2sum :
            route_request(server1)
            routes.push(1)
            server1sum += 1
       else : 
            route_request(server2)
            routes.push(2)
            server2sum += 1

       while routes.length > window :
            x = routes.shift()
            if x == 1 :
                server1sum -= 1
            else : 
                server2sum -= 2
```

Comment: How to adjust the count as time past. only recently call matters.

Comment: Need to calculate a moving average, which requires you to keep a list of routing decisions that's as long as all requests in your window. List can be brief (i.e. 0 for server 1, 1 for server 2, etc. Number of items to keep in array should be estimate of # of requests within you definition of recent.

Comment: or if you want to do a running sum, see above. as long as route_request(...) function hands the request off immediately and doesn't block, it'll work.